# Gradle cannot resolve version that is not requested

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services, onesignal

I am updating Firebase and Google Play services in my Android project. That's how I updated dependencies:

```
//Play Services
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'

//Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.3'
```

When I build my project it fails with following errors:

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.3.4
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.3.4
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.3.4
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.3.4
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.4
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-config:17.3.4
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.3.4
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.3.4
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-common:17.3.4
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.3.4
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:17.3.4
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.3.4
```

For some reason it requires version 17.3.4 for all libraries. How to make it work?

Root gradle file looks as follows:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Are you certain about using that version of com.google.gms:google-services?  The requirement for having all the dependencies at the same version is only a requirement of older versions of that plugin.  Version 4.2.0 should no long ask you to do that.

Comment: @DougStevenson 4.2.0 is specified in root gradle script that is attached. Should it be configured somewhere else as well?

Comment: No, it looks OK to me based on what you're showing here.  Just double check what you're doing.  Maybe try creating a simple project from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved OneSignal plugin to the top of plugins and it helped for some reason.

```
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced issues with OneSignal and dependencies before (e.g. [dependency conflict with itself](https://blog.jakelee.co.uk/fixing-dependency-conflict-in-onesignal-android/)). I'd recommend rolling back to an earlier version of the library, and seeing if it's a recent issue.

Can you also try adding `mavenCentral()` as a repository, as it (at least previously) was hosted there.

Answer (score 0):

In google libraries for some reason it requires that all the versions are equal so it takes the higher version and try to fetch the same version on all the other libraries.

You need to to downgrade the other libraries and put them all at the same version and it will work.

Comment: This is only true for old versions of the google play services plugin.

Comment: It didn't help anyway. When I set all versions to 16.0.0, it started requiring 16.2.2

Comment: hmmm interesting maybe i didin't upgrade my google play services i just avoid having different versions.